# Looping Array properties and break

Tags: javascript

I have some problems with looping and breaking.
I have an array n when i reach 10th element i have to do smth. For example:

```
 $.each(videoDataList,function(k){      
        html = ''
        if(k % 10 == 0){
           html += (k == 0 ? "<ul>" : "</ul><ul>");
        }
        html += '<li class="item">'
        html += '<a href="#" id="vl_'+(k+1)+'">'
        html += '<span class="score_journalist" id="num_'+videoDataList[k].score_journalist+'">'+videoDataList[k].score_journalist+'</span>'
        html += '<img src="/files/preview/s/'+videoDataList[k].video_id+'.jpg" alt="" />'
        html += '<span class="rating clearfloat">'
        html += '<span class="votes"><span class="title">рейтинг:</span> <span class="count">'+videoDataList[k].score_user+'</span></span>'
        html += '</span>'
        html += '<span class="filter"></span>'
        html += '</a>'
        html += '<img src="/files/preview/b/'+videoDataList[k].video_id+'.jpg" alt="" class="big"/>'
        html += '</li>'
        if(k == videoDataList.length){
          html += "</ul>";
        }
        $(html).appendTo('#videoLists ul.list')
    })
```

i want to have 10 elements LI and put them into UL. then i want to loop my array from 11th element till 21th element and again LI from 11 to 21 i want to put in another UL.
Is it possible?

Comment: offtopic: DO NOT call your array `Array`.

Comment: yes, i know. just for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy with the modulo operator:

```
for(k=0;k<=Array.length;k++){

    if(k % 10 == 0 || k == 0)
    {
       if(k > 0)
       {
           html += '</ul>'
       }
       html += '<ul>'
    }


    html += '<li class="item">'
    html += '<a href="#" id="vl_'+(k+1)+'">'
    html += '<span id="num_'+Array[k].prop1+'">'+Array[k].prop1+'</span>'
    html += '<img src="/files/preview/s/'+Array[k].prop2+'.jpg" alt="" />'
    html += '<span class="rating clearfloat">'
    html += '<span class="votes">'+Array[k].prop3+'</span>'
    html += '</span>'
    html += '<span class="filter"></span>'
    html += '</a>'
    html += '<img src="/files/preview/b/'+Array[k].prop4+'.jpg" alt="" class="big"/>'
    html += '</li>'

    if(k == Array.length)
    {
       html += '</ul>'
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(k % 10 == 0){
   html += (k == 0 ? "<ul>" : "</ul><ul>");
}
```

Enter this right after your for loop.

Also before the end of the for loop add:

```
 if(k == Array.length){
  html += "</ul>";
}
```

Is this the thing you were looking for?

Whole code:

```
html = ''   
$.each(videoDataList,function(k){           
    if(k % 10 == 0){            
       html += (k == 0 ? "<ul>" : "</ul><ul>");        
    }         
    html += '<li class="item">'         
    html += '<a href="#" id="vl_'+(k+1)+'">'         
    html += '<span class="score_journalist" id="num_'+videoDataList[k].score_journalist+'">'+videoDataList[k].score_journalist+'</span>'         
    html += '<img src="/files/preview/s/'+videoDataList[k].video_id+'.jpg" alt="" />'                 
    html += '<span class="rating clearfloat">'         
    html += '<span class="votes"><span class="title">рейтинг:</span> <span class="count">'+videoDataList[k].score_user+'</span></span>'         
    html += '</span>'         
    html += '<span class="filter"></span>'         
    html += '</a>'         
    html += '<img src="/files/preview/b/'+videoDataList[k].video_id+'.jpg" alt="" class="big"/>'         
    html += '</li>'         
    if(k == videoDataList.length){           
       html += "</ul>";         
    }            
})         
$(html).appendTo('#videoLists ul.list')  $(html).appendTo('#videoLists ul.list')
```

Comment: That is really weird. Could you copy the code into you opening post so we can see what exactly you are doing? :-)

Comment: you set html to an empty string every time you go into the loop with "html = '';". That leads to the fact that for every item in "videoDataList" you create a ul-element with exactly one li-element. You should do the "html='';" BEFORE the loop and the $(html).appendTo('#videoLists ul.list') AFTER the loop. So your lists are constructed correctly and only then appended to the document. I edited the code in my post to illustrate what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Add this to the top and bottom of your loop.

```
if (k % 10 === 0) {
    // do some work
}
```